# Summarized huge data, How to handle it with R?

Tags: r, summary, forex

I am working on EBS, Forex market Limit Order Book(LOB): here is an example of LOB in a 100 millisecond time slice:

```
datetime|side(0=Bid,1=Ask)| distance(1:best price, 2: 2nd best, etc.)| price
2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,0,1,1.6066
2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,0,2,1.6065
2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,0,3,1.6064
2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,0,4,1.6063
2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,0,5,1.6062

2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,1,1,1.6067
2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,1,2,1.6068
2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,1,3,1.6069
2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,1,4,1.6070
2008/01/28,09:11:28.000,1,5,1.6071

2008/01/28,09:11:28.500,0,1,1.6065 (I skip the rest)
```

To summarize the data, They have two rules(I have changed it a bit for simplicity):

1. If there is no change in LOB in Bid or Ask side, they will not record that side. Look at the last line of the data, millisecond was 000 and now is 500 which means there was no change at LOB in either side for 100, 200, 300 and 400 milliseconds(but those information are important for any calculation).
2. The last price (only the last) is removed from a given side of the order book. In this case, a single record with nothing in the price field. Again there will be no record for whole LOB at that time.

   Example:2008/01/28,09:11:28.800,0,1,

I want to calculate minAsk-maxBid(1.6067-1.6066) or weighted average price (using sizes of all distances as weights, there is size column in my real data). I want to do  for my whole data. But as you see the data has been summarized and this is not routine. I have written a code to produce the whole data (not just summary). This is fine for small data set but for a large one I am creating a huge file. I was wondering if you have any tips how to handle the data? How to fill the gaps while it is efficient.

Comment: I'd suggest you filter and split your data into two data.frames: one for best bids and one for best asks. Then, for each of these two data.frames, use `findInterval` to compute the column of corresponding `ask` or `bid`. Then you'll know how to get to the minimum.

Comment: @flodel- Thanks, it may work here, but there are more complicated calculations that I need all the distances, not just the best bids or asks. Simple example, If I want to calculate weighted price then I need all the distances and I can not filter it. I edited my question.

Comment: for a given timestamp and side, you always have five prices? Please define weighted average price. Is it using all ten prices at a given timestamp, and maybe sizes as weights?

Comment: Now, I am working on EUR/USD and each side is always 10. But EUR/CAD for example, is not the same all the time. Does that make a difference? And for the weighted average price, I am using volume of all ten prices at each timeslice as weights.

Comment: For weighted avg prices, I would use a similar approach but the two initial data.frames should be `weighted.avg.bid` and `weighted.avg.ask`. Then again, use `findInterval` to find the corresponding ask/bid between the two.

Answer (score 3):

You did not give a great reproducible example so this will be pseudo/untested code. Read the docs carefully and make adjustments as needed.

I'd suggest you first filter and split your data into two data.frames:

```
best.bid <- subset(data, side == 0 & distance == 1)
best.ask <- subset(data, side == 1 & distance == 1)
```

Then, for each of these two data.frames, use `findInterval` to compute the corresponding best ask or best bid:

```
best.bid$ask <- best.ask$price[findInterval(best.bid$time, best.ask$time)]
best.ask$bid <- best.bid$price[findInterval(best.ask$time, best.bid$time)]
```

(for this to work you might have to transform date/time into a linear measure, e.g. time in seconds since market opening.)

Then it should be easy:

```
min.spread <- min(c(best.bid$ask - best.bid$price,
                    best.ask$bid - best.ask$price))
```

I'm not sure I understand the end of day particularity but I bet you could just compute the spread at market close and add it to the final `min` call.

---

For the weighted average prices, use the same idea but instead of the two `best.bid` and `best.ask` data.frames, you should start with two `weighted.avg.bid` and `weighted.avg.ask` data.frames.